# Unknown limit in the integral equation

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How to solve for small gamma in the integral equation in Scipy ? I recognize it has to be solved with both the numerical integral and a root solver (Newton's method)

$$ \int_{\gamma}^{+\infty}f(x) dx = 0.01 $$

The function f isn't a known analytical function, it is a probability distribution represented by an array of samples of a histogram.

So essentially the integral is :

$$ \sum_{k = \gamma}^{+\infty} f[k] \Delta x \approx  0.01 $$

Comment: This question is better suited to Stack Overflow

Comment: Agree that S.O. would be better, but note that since $f(x)$ is a p.d.f., it's antiderivative $F(x)$ is a c.d.f. and so by definition is equal to one at infinity. So your problem is essentially to solve $F(\gamma) = 0.99$. Since you only know $f$ approximately as an array, you only know $F$ approximately as the cumulative sum of that array, and you just need to scan it to find either the maximum $\gamma$ with $F(\gamma) \leq 0.99$ or the minimum with $F(\gamma) \geq 0.99$, depending on what you want. There should be no need to use anything from scipy.

Comment: Stack overflow is for software Implementation and bugs questions .... it isn't for numerical  methods, the closest to the question I am asking is either Computational Science or Mathematics

Comment: @jwimberley  That sounds right. I'll look into that.....but just to note, I know that the accumulated sum amount to less than one, the sampling space doesn't represent the population space of the distribution.... I am only working with histogram.